# Merge a column into a flat file and separate chars

Tags: r

So I am trying to convert a column of numbers into a one string, then write each character (number in this case) into a csv as follows.  If there is a better way to solve my problem, please do tell.

```
set.seed(123)
x = data.frame(numbers = sample(001:999, replace = F))

numbers
847
95
350
298
682
806
98
```

to a text file that just has 
    8479535029862898

to a csv file (END GOAL)
8,4,7,9,6,0,2,9,8,6,2,8,9,8

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, we can `paste` the elements together and `strsplit` the whole string by specifying the split as `""`

```
out <- as.numeric(strsplit(paste(x$numbers, collapse = ""), "")[[1]])
```

and write it to a file

```
cat(out, file = "fileout.txt")
```

---

If we are using `python`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': np.random.choice(range(1, 1000), size = 999, replace = True)})
list(map(int, list("".join(map(str, list(x['numbers']))))))
```